# Sum objects based on field value using Streams API

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I wonder if it's possible to do the following in a single line, using the new Streams API:

```
List<MyItem> arr = new ArrayList<>();

// MyItem has a single field, which is a value
arr.add(new MyItem(3));
arr.add(new MyItem(5));

// the following operation is the one I want to do without iterating over the array
int sum = 0;
for(MyItem item : arr){
  sum += item.getValue();
}
```

If the array just contained `int`s, I could've done something like this:

```
int sum = array.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

However, can I apply the same idea to an arbitrary list of objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still do it. Just change the mapping method :

```
int sum = arr.stream().mapToInt(MyItem::getValue).sum();
```

You can even reduce your entire code snippet to a single line :

```
int sum = Stream.<MyItem>Of(new MyItem(3),new MyItem(5)).mapToInt(MyItem::getValue).sum();
```

or even shorter (thanks to @MarkoTopolnik's comment) :

```
int sum = Stream.Of(new MyItem(3),new MyItem(5)).mapToInt(MyItem::getValue).sum();
```

Comment: Btw, one more question. If the value I want, is contained in another object, within MyItem, like this: int value = myItem.getSubitem().VALUE. Then what?

Comment: @habitats I'm not sure if you can chain method references, but you can always use a lambda expression instead - `mapToInt(m -> m.getSubitem().VALUE)`

Comment: You can chain method references if you let the stream do it: `map(MyItem::getSubItem).mapToInt(SubItem::getValue)`.

Comment: @Holger That's a good idea. I didn't think of that. I'm assuming that `mapToInt(MyItem::SubItem::getValue)` wouldn't work though, would it? That's the chaining I had in mind.

Comment: Nope, though you could write it out as a lambda instead of a method reference.